# Azure Function not triggering on Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am pretty new to Azure and I am trying to setup a Function App that is triggered when a message is received by an Event Hub.

Here is my setup:
EventHub:

Event Hubs Namespace - `acc-events`

Event Hub - `hub`

Shared Access Policy attached to `hub` that allows for `Manage, Send, Listen`

Function:

Function App - `accfunction`

Functions - `EventHubTrigger1`

Code in `EventHubTrigger1`:

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs"


using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;

public static async Task Run(EventData[] events, ILogger log)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    foreach (EventData eventData in events)
    {
        try
        {
            string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

            // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
            log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
            await Task.Yield();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
            // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
            exceptions.Add(e);
        }
    }

    // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

    if (exceptions.Count > 1)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

    if (exceptions.Count == 1)
        throw exceptions.Single();
}
```

`function.json`:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "events",
      "connection": "acc-events_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB",
      "eventHubName": "hub",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "eventHubTrigger"
    }
  ]
}
```

Functions Integration page:
[image]

When I add an event to my Event Hub the Function does not trigger.

Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong?

This was all done via following the steps in the UI.

Comment: did you edit your functions.json manually?

Comment: No, that is how it was generated by the UI

Comment: How are you developing your function? cause I dont see any binding in the function definition at all

Answer (score 0):

Function app needs connection string of event hub, to get the events.

Check whether your function app has the application setting **acc-events_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB** under configuration. If not add it as explained below.

Add the connection string of event hub to the function app configuration (Application Setting) with key **acc-events_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB** and value as connection string.